# Adding Header To A SOAP Call (Java equavalent in C#)

Tags: java, c#, api, soap

The SOAP API I am intending to use has given a working example in Java. In every request to the API one should add three values to the header (I just guess they are a domain, a password and api key). To this aim we override the `org.apache.axis.client.Stub` like this:

```
public class SeveraApiStubBase extends org.apache.axis.client.Stub {

    @Override

    public org.apache.axis.client.Call _createCall() throws ServiceException {

        org.apache.axis.client.Call _call = super._createCall();

        _call.addHeader(new org.apache.axis.message.SOAPHeaderElement(
                "http://something.somethingelse.com/", "WebServicePassword", "API_KEY"));

        return _call;
    }

}
```

And then we run the method with the provided header.

I was wondering what the equivalent is in C#.

**Update:** The use of the `IClientMessageInspector` class

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
{
    HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestMessage;
    object httpRequestMessageObject;
    if (request.Properties.TryGetValue(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, out httpRequestMessageObject))
    {
        httpRequestMessage = httpRequestMessageObject as HttpRequestMessageProperty;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(httpRequestMessage.Headers[USER_AGENT_HTTP_HEADER]))
        {
            httpRequestMessage.Headers[USER_AGENT_HTTP_HEADER] = this.m_userAgent;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
        httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add(USER_AGENT_HTTP_HEADER, this.m_userAgent);
        request.Properties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, httpRequestMessage);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use WCF if using C# rather than Axis.  It is a little different of an approach than Axis.

Assuming you're making a client consuming an existing WSDL, you would start by using `svcutil` to generate your service contract code.  [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735103(v=vs.110).aspx) is a link that describes this part.  The example they give is a service with primitive inputs to all operations, so it doesn't show generation of complex type classes.

You can then use [message inspectors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047(v=vs.110).aspx) to intercept the outgoing request and add a header.  The `IClientMessageInspector` interface has the method `BeforeSendRequest` that passes a [Message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.message(v=vs.110).aspx) class as an argument.  The Message class has a `Headers` collection where you can add whatever headers you need.

Comment: I tried using the `IClientMessageInspector` to be honest. But I was somehow puzzled on how to pass my three variables above as `USER_AGENT_HTTP_HEADER` as string. I have updated the question with my code. My project is a console application by the way.

Comment: It is a little more involved.  This link gives more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733786(v=vs.110).aspx Basically you set your 3 variables as properties when you create your instance of your `IClientMessageInspector` implementation.